# {xe|lua}latex + svmono + newfloat + biblatex = ↯

Tags: biblatex, xetex, luatex, sv-classes, newfloat

Running `xelatex` or `lualatex` on

```
\documentclass{svmono}%%% V 5.6 from http://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/resources-guidelines/rights-permissions-licensing/manuscript-preparation/5636
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

spits out the following error:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Patching \addtocontents failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
```

What would be a (permanent) bugfix?

The maintainers have been informed via an e-mail. Though, I'm not sure whether they'll read it; Springer rejects my e-mails on the SMTP level. (How about boycotting Springer for their "friendly" and "welcoming" attitude towards supporting typesetting and scientists in general?)
If they read here, they are kindly asked to feel free to provide a bugfix. (Of course I know that newfloat has not been designed to work this way, but, if we say this, we would have to admit that, broadly speaking, all of (La)TeX itself is one big hack and has been used beyond its limits for ages....)

Crossposts: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32737 , http://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/58

Comment: If you don't load `biblatex` in the MWE and check the `.log` file, you'll see `Package newfloat Info: Unsupported document class, or \@chapter was already redefined by another package.` and a little later `Package newfloat Info: Trying Plan B...` Plan B comes unexpected to `biblatex` ...

Comment: Please note that *If the maintainers read here: please feel free to provide a bugfix.* is not how it works. If you think you have found a bug in any of the involved packages and want to have it fixed, contact the maintainers directly via the means mentioned in package documentation. For `newfloat` that would be https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues, for `biblatex` https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues

Comment: I just note that you edited your question and removed the "Everyone else: any workaround?" bit. Formally this post has now become only a request to the maintainers of the involved packages and not a question. In this form the post would be off-topic here since it is not a question any more. (Of course it is trivial to turn it into a proper question that is on topic.)

Comment: @MdAyq6 quick-and-dirty hacks are very common for all kinds of LaTeX issues as you acknowledge in your question. So feel free to post any kind of fix as an answer to your own question, it may help others even if you don't understand exactly what it does. As for 'official' bugfixes from Springer or the package authors: it is not really expected that such fixes will result from a TeX.SE question, but you did the right thing by creating a Github issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with commit https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/98248cef69723da296b4d24e8837fe6a1103d60b

I will push a new version of the "caption package bundle" to CTAN soon; in the meantime please use https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/raw/master/tex/newfloat.sty as replacement of the old newfloat.sty.

Comment: @MdAyq6 Thanks for the feedback! Will do within the very next days.